# layout-xxhdpi/layout-xxlarge not supported on Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, android-studio

Not supported on Android Studio. I want to create a layout new phones, like Galaxy S4. I have one to test on and the sizes are too small. But android studio compiler gives an error, because that forward slash is appearing. I tried layout-xxlarge, it give an error too.

```
android-apt-compiler: [xxxxxxxxxx] invalid resource directory name:
```

C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Dropbox\android_studio_workspace\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\res/layout-xxlarge

Are these layouts supported on Eclipse?

Comment: use eclipse is best way and don't use android studio (still to beta version) until will be stable version released!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), section "Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2":

> For the first generation of tablets running Android 3.0, the proper
>   way to declare tablet layouts was to put them in a directory with the
>   xlarge configuration qualifier (for example, res/layout-xlarge/). In
>   order to accommodate other types of tablets and screen sizes—in
>   particular, 7" tablets—Android 3.2 introduces a new way to specify
>   resources for more discrete screen sizes. The new technique is based
>   on the amount of space your layout needs (such as 600dp of width),
>   rather than trying to make your layout fit the generalized size groups
>   (such as large or xlarge).

The best you can get is:

```
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

The ones you need are defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: I tried to make a folder called layout-sw600dp / layout-sw1080dp / layout-w1080dp, but it keeps using default layout folder, with hdpi.

Comment: On which device do you test it?

Comment: Yes, then it's obvious that your problem comes from the `AndroidStudio` itself. I'm not happy to say it, but it has many problems. However, if you switch to Android Eclipse SDK, your problems will probably dissapear. Try that one for now, `AndroidStudio` is still beta...

Comment: Before Android Studio I used Eclipse, I just like how Android Studio looks and works, I guess it's too fast to use it completely. Thanks.

Comment: If you like Android Studio, you could give IntelliJ IDEA a try, I have used it for Android development for about 2 years now and it works just like Android Studio, with a few of the newer (but buggy) parts missing :)